# AVPlayer video from temporary directory after recording stops playing after few seconds

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, grand-central-dispatch, avplayer

I have a custom camera, which can record videos and take photos. The problem is after recording and pushing viewController with recorded video preview, video stops playing after few seconds. 
So the flow is:

> 1. Custom camera opened;
> 2. I've recorded a video;
> 3. Controller with recorded video preview is shown. (by pushViewController(controller, animated: true));
> 4. Video started playing;
> 5. After N seconds (1-2 sec) video stopped for some reason.

The code:

1. didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL:

```
        if let error = error {
            // handle error
            return
        }

        if let currentBackgroundRecordingID = backgroundRecordingID {
            backgroundRecordingID = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid

            if currentBackgroundRecordingID != UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid {
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(currentBackgroundRecordingID)
            }
        } 
       // open viewController and play recently recorded video from temporary files.
```

2. setupVideoBackground() -> Configuration for AVPlayer, called in viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear:

```
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        player.actionAtItemEnd = .none

        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 0)

        player.seek(to: .zero)
        player.play()
```

3. Pushing view controller:

```
        let vc = TestController()
        vc.url = url!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

**Note: One weird thing, that if I use pushViewController with animated: false, then player will be playing full video and if with animated: true, video will be stopped after few seconds. Also, present view controller works perfectly.**

**Note 2: If I call setupVideoBackground() with 0.5 seconds delay by using DispatchQueue, video won't stops.**

I don't understand, why video is playing correctly after `pushViewController(vc, animated: false)` and stops playing after `pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`

Comment: Does it maybe stop right when the animation is finished? Have you tried starting the video after the animation is finished?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel by "animation" you mean animation provided by pushViewController?

Comment: Right. It seems to be related somehow...

Comment: @FrankSchlegel I downloaded similar projects with camera and video recording/preview and they use same approach as mine, so I'm confused a lot because code is almost exactly the same ..

Comment: Strange… You could try to use KVO to observe the player’s `rate`, set a breakpoint in the callback and check the stack for the reason of the change.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel I noticed that when animation is true, ```timeControlStatus```  returns
```waitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate``` few times and then returns  ```paused``` value. So it means that ```rate``` value is 0.0. Now I need to understand, why rate becomes 0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
So the problem was in `viewDidDissapear` on the camera screen. There was a `cameraSession.stopSession()`. Each time stopSession was called, avplayer stops playing. I don't know why and how `AVCaptureSession.stopSession()` is related to `AVPlayer`, but removing `cameraSession.stopSession()` from `viewDidDissapear` fixed the problem.

**Solution 2:**
You can set AVAudioSession category to `.playAndRecord` and video will plays correctly:

`try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .videoRecording, options: [.mixWithOthers])`